# Getting Undefined dependecy on controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m using loopback with angular JS. I have a Person model on loopback and generated the lb-services.js to get acces to the Person model.

I added the lb-services to the module:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('frontend', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toastr','lbServices']);

})();
```

However on my PersonsController when calling the `createPerson()` method I´m getting that `Persons` is undefined. I don´t understand why, since I have the dependecy on the controller.

This is my code:

```
angular.module('frontend').controller('PersonsController',['$scope','Person',function($scope){
  $scope.person = {name:'guest',last_name:"none",age:55};

  $scope.createPerson= function(){
    console.log("CREATING PERSON...");
    Person.create({name:$scope.person.name,last_name:$scope.person.last_name,age:$scope.person.age}).$promise
      .then(function(){
          console.log("Created person.")
      });

  };

}])
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You are not including Person in your controller function ['$scope','Person',function($scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('frontend').controller('PersonsController',['$scope','Person',function($scope, Person){
```

just add Person as second parameter in function declaration and read the docs about DI in angular.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That solved my problem :)